# Elasticsearch not able to fetch more than 10 documents using Java API Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am reading file path from one index named as `documents` from that filepath and reading the file and indexing those file contents in another index named as `documents_attachment` using java code.

so, during the first process, am not able to fetch more than `10` records  at a time, Its giving only `10` records from 
the `document` index. I have more than `100000` records in my `doucment` index.

How can i fetch all the `100000` records at a time.

I have tried with `searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);` then its indexing till `10K` records not more than that, and this method not allowing me to give more than `10000` as size.

Please find my below java code that am using.

```
public class DocumentIndex {

private final static String INDEX = "documents";  
private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment"; 
private final static String TYPE = "doc";
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
    Document doc=new Document();

    logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

    try {
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
    //searchSourceBuilder.size(10000); 
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
         searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
    logger.info("Total Hits --->"+totalHits);


    File all_files_path = new File("d:\\All_Files_Path.txt");
    File available_files = new File("d:\\Available_Files.txt");
    File missing_files = new File("d:\\Missing_Files.txt");
    all_files_path.deleteOnExit();
    available_files.deleteOnExit();
    missing_files.deleteOnExit();
    all_files_path.createNewFile();
    available_files.createNewFile();
    missing_files.createNewFile();

    int totalFilePath=1;
    int totalAvailableFile=1;
    int missingFilecount=1;

    Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
    for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

        String encodedfile = null;
        File file=null;

        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();


        if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
            doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
            doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));
        }

        String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());



        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(all_files_path, true))  ){
            out.println("FilePath Count ---"+totalFilePath+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
        }

        file = new File(filepath);
        if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                  try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(available_files, true))  ){
                        out.println("Available File Count --->"+totalAvailableFile+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                        totalAvailableFile++;
                    }
                FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
                fileInputStreamReader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(missing_files, true));
            out.close();
            missingFilecount++;
        }

        jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
        jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
        jsonMap.put("fileContent", encodedfile);

        String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                .source(jsonMap)
                .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);

        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("d:\\exception.txt"));
        try {
            IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(request);

        } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
            if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace(printStream);
        }

        totalFilePath++;


    }

    logger.info("Indexing done.....");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient memory, increase the index setting `index.max_result_window` from 10000 to the number you require.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings

Note however, that this will not scale indefinitely. Search requests take heap memory and time proportional to from + size. This setting is used to limit that memory and you'll run out of memory if you set it too high.

The easiest way to set this is via the REST API:

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "max_result_window" : 150000
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks., for me this is one time activity. Only once i have to fetch `100K` records and have to index with another name. so i can follow this approach rite.? and where i can set `index.max_result_window: 150000` this ? . In `elasticsearch.yml` file. ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how to set this.

Comment: Note - if this is to copy to another index, you could look at using the reindex API instead: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Actually, i have to read `filepath` from first index (filepath available in Oracle DB), then with the help of the `filepath` and reading the actual file which is in my local drive, then i have to attach the file content in the same index (if possible). Am new to ES, so that am creating another index and attaching the file content in the new (second) index.